# Одновременная вставка и сбор статистики

Tags: oracle, plsql, статистика, insert

Допустим, выполняется вставка записей в таблицу (до commit) в одной сессии и одновременно запущен сбор статистики по ней в другой сессии.

Будет ли собираться статистика, или она будет ожидать фиксацию изменений в таблице?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, сбор статистики не будет ожидать незафиксированых изменений в другой сессии:

```sql
create table tab1 (id number);
insert into tab1 
        select rownum from dual connect by level <= 1e6;

1,000,000 rows inserted.
```

В другой сессии:

```sql
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (user, 'TAB1');

select num_rows
from user_tables
where table_name = 'TAB1';

  NUM_ROWS
----------
         0
```

Answer (score 3):

В обычном случае сборщик статистики не видит данных, которые ещё не зафиксированы. Он фиксирует текущую транзакцию, собирает статистику и снова фиксирует. Но в 12.1+ статистика может собираться для bulk операций (`CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT, INSERT INTO ... SELECT`) "на лету" при выполнении некоторых условий. См. статью: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/online-statistics-gathering-for-bulk-loads-12cr1.

Comment: То есть сбор статистики будет выполняться, а не ожидать фиксацию записей (при обычном построчном insert)?

Comment: В ссылке идёт речь о сборе статистики на "лету" при выполнении вставки. ТС вроде это не спрашивает. @АнатолийЭрнст Так ли это?

Comment: Не думаю, что он будет ждать. Он будет собирать статистику по тому, что видит (т.е. тому, что зафиксировано). Ждать всех транзакций - это странно.

Comment: @0xdb я просто назвал способ сбора статистики "на лету" при выполнении вставки. И описал обычную вставку. Или "в обычном случае сборщик статистики не видит данных, которые ещё не зафиксированы" неверно? Я всегда так считал.

Comment: Верно, но вопрос то не - "_видит или не видит_?", а - "_будет ли собираться статистика или она будет ожидать фиксацию изменений в таблице?_".  Подождём автора, что он скажет.